# iOS UIScrollView with UIWebView and UITableView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I have a complex design to create. I want to have something like this

```
- UIScrollView
   --UILabel
   --UILabel
   --UIWebView
   --UITableView
   --UITextField
   --UIButton
```

I am using a Storyboard and I want the ScrollView to take the height of the Full Webview and the TableView so that there is only one parent scrolling and other scrolls are disabled and the whole page seems like one single view.

Right now, the whole UI looks very messed up and only the Webview and table view scroll indivisually and the parent scrollview not scrolling at all making the labels and textfields have a constant place and the button not showing at all.

**EDIT**
Using raki's solution, I used a TableViewController. I have something like below:
[image]

But the webView does not cover its full content and just shows in the area shown in the image.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: take a UITableViewController, place those two labels and web view in table header and text field and button in table footer and show the middle content in tableview cells

Comment: set the contentSize of scrollview as ScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,(Height of UITableview+Height of WebView+height of other controlls));

Comment: @raki I tried your solution but the WebView still does not cover the height of its content and shows in a small size with a scroll.. How can I make the webview take the full height of the content

Comment: @raki please check m Edit

Comment: @helloworld you can change the height as you required

Comment: @raki the webview is still scrollable and the labels are always static. If I disable the scroll on the webview nothing can be scrolled